# 02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

Step 1:

I have script to disable constraints and trigger. this is successfully executed.

Step 2:

I have script to truncate tables. this is also executed successfully.

Step 3:

But when i try to enable constraints and trigger, I am getting below error.

```
Error report -
ORA-02298: cannot validate (EMPLOYEE.FK_829_EMP_STATUS) - parent keys not found
ORA-06512: at line 6
02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
*Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
           child records.
*Action:   Obvious
```

Comment: Your truncate script apparently missed at least one table.

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint you're enabling on the EMPLOYEE table has records that don't exist in the parent table. Look at the constraint you're enabling and either delete the orphaned children, add the records back to the parent, or use the NOVALIDATE clause so that the constraint will be enabled even with orphaned children (just know you have some violations that you've "ok'd" that will exist in the table).

To find information on the constraint:

```
select * 
from dba_constraints 
where constraint_name = 'FK_829_EMP_STATUS'
```

Look for the R_CONSTRAINT_NAME column, then:

```
select * 
from dba_constraints 
where constraint_name = '<r_constraint_name_value_from_above>'
```

If you want the columns, you can query dba_cons_columns `where constraint_name = 'xxxx'`

Either way, that will give you the picture of the tables and columns involved so you can, as I previously stated, fix the data or enable with NOVALIDATE.

-Jim